# How to bulk update in sequelize with experssJs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, bulkupdate

I have the follwing set of data

```
 const data =    [{
      name: 'test2',
      desc: test2,
      id: 2, 
    },
    {
      name: 'test3',
      desc: test3,
      id: 3,

    },
    {
      name: 'test4',
      desc: test4,
      id: 4,

    },
 ]
```

I want to update using sequelize, i don't want to use any kind of loop to update. However I've tried bulkCreate with updateOnDuplicate

```
 await  models.project.bulkCreate(data, {
    updateOnDuplicate: ['id'],
  },
```

But I'm not able to update and getting sequalize error. Can anyone tell the optimized solutions for the same?

Comment: What error did you get? And I suppose you need to indicate all fields you need to update in `updateOnDuplicate` option

Comment: @Anil Optimized solution: Use loop!

Comment: Anyway, there is no SQL query that allows you to update several records with individual sets of values for each one.